# View Controller doesn't dealloc when perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uicollectionview, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a problem in my apps that its memory increase constantly. So here is my app structure. I am using `SWrevealViewController` for slidemenu.

```
Slidemenu
    - View Controller A
    - View Controller B
    - View Controller C
```

My View Controller A consist of `UICollectionView` and `ScrollView`. 
When I perform segue from View Controller A to View Controller B, the memory is doing fine. But if I am going to View Controller A with slide menu, the memory increases. 
Here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` on SWRevealViewController's table delegate. I am using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if isLoggedIn {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(idSegueLoggedIn[indexPath.row], sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then I am going to View Controller B via slide menu and then going to View Controller A again, on that point memory increases constantly.

It looks like my View Controller A that consist of `UICollectionView` doesn't release its object on memory. But if I remove my `UICollectionView`, my memory issue was dissapear and it runs well.

So I think it was about my reference to `UICollectionView`. I already declared that with `weak` property but it does nothing.

```
@IBOutlet weak var othersCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

I try to called deinit() in my View Controlle A but it doesn't called.

Here is my memory usage graph, on each "black arrow", I move to View Controller A with slide menu.

Pls let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thank you so much.
[image: Memory Usage]

Comment: Try to implement deinit() in ViewController A and then go to ViewController B through side menu, if it is not called then your class is still in stack. Again go to ViewController A from side menu and check whether viewDidLoad() gets called in ViewController A again. If so then your class is loaded twice.

Comment: I declared `deinit{print("deinit vc A")}` on View Controller A and moving from  A to B to A to B to A to B ad so on but it never get called.

Comment: deinit() will be called only if A gets remove from stack. In current case when user move from class A to B, the class A still remain in the memory.

Comment: That is my question. My stack never get decreased with SWRevealViewController on View Controller with UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

I am answering a bit late but I had a similar problem. I the end my problem was linked to the declaration of delegates in some UITableViewCell. I fixed the problem by declaring the delegate variable as weak.

Here is an example :

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myNameTextField: UITextField!

weak var delegate: CellDbErrorDelegate?
```